# Why mail goes to Spam or Junk folder by using Grails mail plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am currently using grails mail plugin in my grails projects .Following is the version.

plugins.mail=1.0.1 and my grails version is app.grails.version=2.0.3

When i am using sendMail closure the mail is going to the user's spam folder in most of the cases .Is there any way so that mail only go to inbox of the user .

Below is my code.

```
def sendNotificationMail(def user, subjectText, bodyText){
    println "sending mail"
    if(verifyEmailLimit(user)){
        try{
            mailService.sendMail {
                to user.emailAddress
                from grailsApplication.config.notificationmail.from
                subject subjectText
                body bodyText
            }
            return true
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            println ex.getMessage()
            return false
        }
    }
    else
    return false
}
```

Comment: has the "from" account any problem? what's the grailsApplication.config.notificationmail.from value?

Comment: @Miguel Prz notificationmail.from = "info@tpsynergy.com"

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this issue isn't related to the grails email plugin. In fact, it's basically a wrapper for java-mail api.

I've been using grails mail for a long time and haven't had any problem with it.

On the other hand, I suffered a bit with emails being marked as SPAM. However, it's much more a client server problem (specially hotmail).

You can a run a keyword checker to make sure your email hasn't got much "SPAMMED" words. (i.g.:http://www.emailspamtest.com/)

Besides that, you can also use some kind of special SMTP service, like mailchimp.